# Flash can't sent HTTP request after beforeunload from javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

I need to send a request from flash right before the swf is unloaded. I've seen a bunch of posts on this, but none with answers that work for me.

I couldn't find a way to detect unloading from within the flash, so I had to implement an external interface to notify the flash from javascript that the user is about to leave the page.

Somthing like this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    swfobject.unload()
});
```

The problem is that I can't seem to send any requests from flash when chrome calls the external interface at this point, it works if I call `swfobject.unload()` whenever the page isn't unloading. And it also works from IE and Firefox.

**Why doesn't it work in chrome?**

Does Chrome for some reason disable all http requests for the flash once `beforeunload` is triggered?

Is there a relaible way to do this, to make sure a request is always sent before the user leaves the page? There should be lot's of flash plugins that need to send requests for various reasons before unload.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried jQuery?

something like this:

```
$(window).unload(
    function ()
    {
        swfobject.unload()
    }
);
```

Comment: Yes I have, I've even tried `$(window).on( "unload", function....`. But still doesn't send requests when the external interface is called from chrome. But thanks! Tips and questions like this might give me ideas.